# Using a arraylist instead of a dataset

Tags: java

I want offline/local storage of data. In c# ado.net you have dataset,datatables to do this. I can't find the equivalent of dataset in java. I am thinking about using a arraylist. Do you think this is a good idea?

Edit: I am trying to store data from twitter. I am trying to store it in something like a Datatable(in my case a Arraylist). I am going to send the data from the DataTable(in my case a Arraylist) to the database.

Comment: Depending upon how you are going to put it into the database, you may want to look at a `BlockingQueue`, as they are easier to write consumers against. This question, though, is a bit undefined.

Comment: Search for data persistence. Because you "`Datatable`" will not persistent the end of the process. So this will only be store while the process is running

Comment: You need to show us the relevant Java code then.  My guess is that Twitter Java API you are using already has a prescribed method for handling the data it receives.

Comment: You can define a data structure to store a record of you want to store (a class), and store reference to each such record in `ArrayList<RecordClass>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want a temporary place to put the data and send it sequentially to the database an ArrayList is a convenient collection.

If you want to work with the data in memory and need quick access to records by a key, you can use a HashMap.

And if you need quick access by a key and to be able to read the values sequentailly in a certain order you can use a Treemap.

Comment: Thanks this is what i wanted to know.